# Javascript and a Blank Web Page

Tags: javascript, function, html

I'm struggling to initialize a function in JavaScript. I'm fairly new to it, and can't seem to see the problem in my code. Every time I test it, I just see a blank web page. Here's a snippet of the code where I think the problem is:

```
function initialize(){
    cities();
};

//function to create a table with cities and their populations
function cities(){
    //define two arrays for cities and population
        var cityPop = [
            { ...
```

I've looked through lessons on codecademy, and been browsing around for answers but can't seem to figure it out. Any advice?

Comment: Well I mean.... what do you expect to SEE other then a blank page, your script doesn't really do any rendering/DOM manipulation for you to notice

Comment: Megan, you may need to post more than that. What you posted has nothing to do with a blank page. Look at the browser's developer tools console, are there any error messages? Start there as it may tell you exactly where a syntax error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the initialize function also which will call the cities function

```
function initialize(){
    cities();
};

//function to create a table with cities and their populations
function cities(){
    //define two arrays for cities and population
        var cityPop = [
            { ...}]
}
initialize();
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that later on in my code where I was calling the initialize function, there was a bracket that got misplaced. It works now!